# Is my web service binding a connection?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm currently consuming from a web service using Java. My setup code looks something like this:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(myAuth);
service = new The_Service().getWSHttpBindingITheService();

Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext();
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList(username));
headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList(password));
requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url);
```

And then I consume like this:

```
TheResult r = service.getTheResult(resultId);
```

This is all fine and dandy, but my understanding of how this setup works is limited. What I'm wondering is: **Is this a live connection, or does it work as separate requests?**

The reason for my questioning is I'm uncertain if I need to handle reconnecting. If it fails, will all consecutive requests fail, or just the one while the service is out of order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like you are using an HTTPBinding

There are different examples on the Web which shows what's transferred via network like on [MkYong](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/)

When you have a look at the "Tracing the SOAP Traffic" section you can see it's just a usual HTTP Request / Response.

When sending two request they they are treated separate requests. 
When HTTP keep alive is used, they may use the same connection.

Consecutive requests will be successful as soon as the server is alive and working properly.